# QT Installation on new MAC: Am I missing something?

Tags: qt

opened the sources zip, did the "configure" and "make" parts. Everything seems to be okay, but somehow, when I run the "designer", or any other app built there, i am getting "Designer cannot be opened because of a problem". As a (windows) developer, i am thinking 'missing DLLs' or missing libraries, but this doesn't make sense. the lengthy build process was fine. Am I missing an environment string or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new to Mac, download and install the pre-packaged Qt SDK will make your life a lot easier.
http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/sdk-mac-os-cpp

Comment: Are there instructions somewhere as to the steps you need to take to build the environment from scratch? I mean, the "configure" and "make" steps went fine, it seems like something extra is missing.

Comment: http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/install-mac.html you may have missed the install part after the make step.